# Array bound to AG-Grid React not updated when user inputs in editable field of the AG-Grid table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using AG-Grid react and I am binding an array to the rows of the AG-grid. There is a column called "comments" which takes users input. The default value is blank. After I input some data to the field.
The array that is binded to the AG Grid does not get updated, the comments still remains blank. I am trying to send this array to the backend with the new input comments from the user. How do i achieve this?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getData} from '../service';

const MainPage = ({data})=>{

    const [rowData,setRowData] = useState([]);
    const [columnDefs,setColDefs] = useState([]);

    const prepareCol = ()=>{
        fields = [];
        fields.push({
            field: "ID"
        });

        fields.push({
            headerName: 'comments',
            editable: true,
            valueSetter: params=>{
                if(params.data['comments']!==params.newValue){
                    // assigning new value
                    params.data['comments'] = params.newValue;
                }
                return true;

            },
            valueGetter: params=>{
                return params.data.comments;
            }
        });
        return fields;
    }

    
    useEffect(()=>{
        getData().then(res=>{
            setRowData(res['rowData']);
            setColDefs(prepareCol);
            
        })
    },[])

    return(
    <>
        <div style={{height: 100, width: '100%'}}>
            <AgGridReact>
                rowData={rowData}
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
            </AgGridReact>
        </div>
       
    </>
    )
}

export default MainPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need valueGetter & valueSetter for this. Just adding `editable: true` should work.

And I found some mistakes in your code as well. AgGridReact component should use a self-closing tag for your case. So I made some changes. This should be working

```js
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]);
  const [columnDefs, setColDefs] = useState([
    { field: "ID" },
    {
      field: "comments",
      editable: true,
    },
  ]);
  const gridRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((res) => {
      setRowData(res["rowData"]);
    });
  }, []);

  const getAllData = () => {
    gridRef.current.api.forEachNode((node) => {
      // Put your logic here
      console.log(node);
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 500, width: 500 }}>
        <AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          onCellValueChanged={(params) => console.log(params)} // You can see the changed value
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
```